# What do i need and how do I start to adjust the css of a website with "encrypted" .gz files

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7, gzip

I want to help a friend out with his website. I need to change some styling in the css but i do not have drupal experience. In the css folder i found a lot of .gz css files with (what looks to me) encrypted names.

If i want to start editing these css files. How do i start? If i google it, i can find some information about gzip, but i don't know what the most practical solution would be.

Thank you for your help. This is how the folder looks like:

[image: css folder drupal site]

EDIT 1:
I found the css map with normal css files:

[image]

But changing these files, doesn't change anything. When i go to the website and inspect the elements. The inspect shows me the name of the files you see in the picture above in my question:

[image]

I hope this information helps.

Comment: the rights css sources is in theme folder, those gz is a result of aggregation of all of them. You need to edit css sources in theme folder.

Comment: I found the css, thank you. There is also a "sass" folder between the css files. is this a problem or not?

EDIT: i changed main.css, but no changes appear.

Comment: you have to use compass/sass to compile and generate css files https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DrrVjpMUxxU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For front-end some theme is used. From admin menu go to "Appearance" to find out what theme is used.

Then that theme should be located at "sites/all/themes/theme_name"

Inside that folder there should be theme info file, called:

theme_name.info

That file is defining CSS/JSS files that are going to be added to all pages (for adding those file to specific pages there is other way), so there should be lines like:

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/reset.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/style_gd.css
```

So, there you can see what CSS files are included, add you own and so similar. Make sure to clear drupal's cache after changing this file.

So you can change some of the files listed there...or add your own and add it to theme info file.

If some kind of caching is turned on ("Configuration -> Development -> Performance" from admin menu) then multiple files can be merged into one, compressed and similar...

Comment: Hi Milan,
Thank you for your help. I have found the files, changed something in css and nothing changes. I also tried to clear the cache via the performance tab in drupal. There is also a tab "advanced css/js aggregation", but in that tab are only change options actions and only a few cron maintenance tasks like delete orphaned aggregates, refresh all locale files,... what should i do?

Comment: Under that "Advanced css/js aggregation" go to last "Operations" tab and try that "Flush AdvAgg Cache" button.